# ObjectPool that implements CopyOnWrite

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying to design a template class that acts as a factory to create a type (lets say an object) efficiently. Additionally, the objects created should be unique and no two objects that have same values on its members should be created. The user of the class is expected to supply a hashing function (similar to std::unordered_map C++11) that will help in deciding if a new object needs creation or an existing object can be used. A mechanism to decide when to dispose the object when it is no longer used is required.

The problem: An object pool generally pre allocates a group of objects and reduces time to allocate and deallocate. However, in this case, as reference counting is required, how can this be achieved. Not sure how one can use std::shared_ptr within an object pool.

Edit: The copy on write bit: If a user using the object decides to change the object, then he will have to get hold of a new object or an existing object with the value that he is changing the object to.
Also, the Object should have a operator == defined as commented.

Comment: In addition to hash, the user also has to define an equals function (or just ensure that `operator==` does the right thing). That aside, you can't preallocate objects when you don't know what their contents are. You can *cache* them, however. And you never mention copy-on-write in your actual question. I think you need to rewrite your question a bit.

Comment: C++ isn't powerful enough to encapsulate and reuse copy-on-write-ness. A programmer needs to do implement it himself for each of his classes separately.

Comment: I see nothing tricky, so long as the operations for writing are reasonably simple.  `shared_ptr` can have a deleter that runs arbitrary code.  Use `pImpl` to immutable pattern, where write operations return a new `pImpl` via the object pool (which can be the old one).  Your operations are of type `T(T,Args...)`, and produce operations of the type `void(COW<T>&,Args...)` basically.  Am I missing something @n.m.?

Comment: @Yakk Perhaps I misunderstand something. Can you show a minimal compilable example of `template class COW<class T>`?

Comment: @n.m. that is a lot of work!  I am saying it looks possible and isn't tricky, not that it is trivial.  :)  If I have an hour free I'll see what I can do, but no promises.  The signature above isn't optimal: now that I thin about it, `tuple<X...>(T const&, Args...)` where `X...` can construct a `T` and be hashed transparently as an operation, and the `COW` produces `void(COW<T>&,Args...)`.  You'd have to write each (source) operation manually.  Ok, maybe is tricky.

Comment: @n.m. only took 15 minutes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f92c3c8183f1184 -- needs more work to be fully efficient, but as written it isn't bad.

Comment: @Yakk This is really nice but the user still needs to call `modify` each time explicitly, which kind of ruins the whole idea. I was hoping for a transparent COW wrapper. Oh well.

Comment: @n.m. The syntax, it can be improved.  `x.modify( &X::method, args... )` for example, or even `x.modify(&X::method)( args... )` or `x.m(&X::method)(args...)` or `(x^&X::method)(args...)` as examples.  Not completely transparent, but close.

Comment: @Yakk: Is it using variadic templates? Unable to build. I think VS2012 does not support it.

Comment: @ram vs2012 only supports c++11 if one is feeling generous